# How to test keyup enter on button in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm working on an application where accessibility is very important. As a part of this, we have a number of different components that we want to ensure are accessible via mouse events and keyboard events. We are trying to setup unit tests around these requirements as well to ensure that any changes made to these components will still adhere to these standards. We have run into an issue with buttons. I have a sample application to demonstrate:

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  console = console;

  actionTaken($event) {
    this.console.log($event);
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<!-- <button
  (click)="actionTaken($event)"
  (keyup.enter)="actionTaken($event)">
    Take Action
</button> -->

<button
  (click)="actionTaken($event)">
    Take Action
</button>
```

The html has two buttons, one is listening to a click event and the other is listening to a click event and an enter keyup event.

The one with two event listeners is the one I would assume I would need to use, but when I use that one, I can see that when I hit enter on the button, the event gets fired twice, once as a keyup and the other as a click.

The one with one event listener, when I use that one, I can see that when I hit enter on the button, the event gets fired only once, as a click event.

I can use the second one thought I'm not certain that the application will perform that way across browsers. Also, I tried to setup unit tests to validate that this is functioning according to our contractual obligations(enter and mouse click should both work) and I can't figure out how to write the tests.

Here is what I've tried so far.

`app.component.spec.ts`

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('clicking on button should take action', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, 'actionTaken');

    fixture.nativeElement
           .querySelector('button')
           .click();

    expect(component.actionTaken).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('clicking on button should log to console', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component.console, 'log');

    fixture.nativeElement
           .querySelector('button')
           .click();

    expect(component.console.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('pressing enter on button should take action', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, 'actionTaken');

    fixture.nativeElement
           .querySelector('button')
           .dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'enter', bubbles: true }));

    expect(component.actionTaken).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('pressing enter on button should log to console', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component.console, 'log');

    fixture.nativeElement
           .querySelector('button')
           .dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'enter', bubbles: true }));

    expect(component.console.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Utilizing the button listening to both events, all of these tests pass, but when I run the code in the browser, I can see that the tests aren't being truthful as the enter key actually fires the method twice, not once like the tests are indicating.

Utilizing the button listening only to the click event though, the 'enter' key tests fail, though the functionality appears to be working in the browser.

This only seems to be an issue with buttons. Other types of HTML elements don't seem to work this way.

What is the proper way to write the component, events, and tests, so that the desired method will only be called once with a mouse click and with the enter key and the tests will be setup properly to validate this?

Comment: I think that a button type="submit" always respond to a Enter key

Comment: Thanks for the comment. type="submit" seems to be the default type. I have also tried type="button" which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) should have no default behavior and I'm still seeing the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#activation-behavior) has a notion of element `activation`. Pressing `enter` key is just one way to activate the button. User can also press `space` key or use other methods to activate the button (voice controlling, etc). Normally the `activation` culminates into `click` event on that element. The question is: do all the browser implement the spec the same way? Are buttons activated with `enter` key in every browser?

If you want to make sure that your button reacts to `enter` key, you could leave both handlers on your button and check in your `click` handler whether the event is `synthetic` or `authentic`.

Problem that your test lies to you and says that everything is correct may have multiple sources. First it depends on which browser you are running your tests against. PhantomJS might behave differently as other browser. Second problem might be that you are creating synthetic `keyup` event in your test and the browser might behave differently for synthetic events in regards to activation process. I have tested this in Chrome and in fact Chrome doesn't activate the button when the event is synthetic.

I would just use `click` handler and leave the activation process on the browser and manually test how different browsers supported by the app behave. In the test i would just emit the `click` event.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The standard Angular setup runs the tests through Chrome. If I'm understanding you correctly, pressing the `enter` key would be a `synthetic` event? Also, if I were to go the route of ignoring `synthetic` click events, I would lose the others you speak about like `space`? Also, this doesn't answer the question. Your suggestion is for manually testing, which is what I'm hoping to avoid. Today it is a `button`, maybe tomorrow the design team will change it to an `a` or `div` at which point we will have to know to manually test them all again.

Comment: Yes, when user presses `enter` browser creates synthetic click event. Yes, when you handle `keyup` events and only handle `enter` key events and ignore all synthethic click events, then you would lose all synthethic events that caused button to activate. So it looks like bad idea :)

Comment: My suggestion is to unit test only the click handler and don't bother testing all possible synthetic click events and different behaviours of the browsers. But if you really want to test keyup, then you have to find a way how to dispatch key event that triggers synthethic click, if that's even possible. Maybe some e2e testing framework which is capable of replicating native user keyboard input could help.